# Make Sentry On-Premise installation more lightweight

Tags: exception, error-handling, sentry, errbit, exceptionless

Is there any way to lower the amount of dependent services and/or the amount of resources Sentry is using?

Because I am thinking whether [*a minimum* of 8GB of RAM](https://github.com/getsentry/onpremise#requirements) is *worth* having error tracking for a small amount of projects.

Or whether I should rather use simpler(?) self-hosted solutions like [Exceptionless](https://github.com/exceptionless/Exceptionless), [Glitchtip](https://glitchtip.com/), [Coderr](https://github.com/coderrio/coderr.server/), [Errbit](https://github.com/errbit/errbit) or whatnot.
I don't have experience with any of them because I mainly used Sentry so far. Therefore I would rather prefer to make Sentry more lightweight (if somehow possible).

Otherwise the Sentry-fork [Glitchtip](https://glitchtip.com/) probably makes a good bet because it doesn't(?) rely on [so many services](https://github.com/getsentry/onpremise/blob/88991582c5a4d9ed9210ac5dcdd7efe03d4455ba/docker-compose.yml#L12-L21) yet.

Comment: If it's a "simple" project you likely can use sentry.io for free instead of spending the time and money to maintain your own instance.

Comment: Sure, I obviously know that, which I _explicitly_ asked regarding the on-premise installation.
But:
**1.** I didn't claim that I have 'a "simple" project'. I'm looking for a self-hosted solution that is simpler regarding it's resources.
**2.** Apart from Sentry and Coderr (it doesn't have a Docker image) the alternatives are quick and simple to install & maintain. I don't know how much resources they take.
**3.** It obviously have various privacy advantages if I can host error data on own servers.

So can I assume that it's _not_ possible to make the Sentry installation more lightweight?

Comment: For anyone reading this: I'm currently trying Exceptionless which feels very fast and the whole setup uses much less resources on my machines. The major memory eaters are Redis and Elasticsearch and I didn't do anything yet to make them consume less (I'm using [the standard Docker setup](https://github.com/exceptionless/Exceptionless/blob/master/samples/docker-compose.yml)). at the moment.
It might not yet have [a supported client for your language though](https://github.com/exceptionless?q=client).

Comment: Hello, I started GlitchTip and want to note that being lightweight is a core value we have. It requires only PostgreSQL and Redis.

Comment: @MaxMuster does Sentry run on a Pi? I mean, Sentry is the reference here. This is why I created this question in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

The Sentry 10 release added a lot more dependencies and components than what we had in version 9. The minimum services required to run Sentry 10 are these:

- Postgresql
- Redis
- Kafka
- Zookeeper
- Snuba api
- Clickhouse server
- Sentry

Note that some services may need additional services to function. For example, Kafka and Zookeeper both require having Java on the machine. If you are running all these services on the same machine, a decent machine is needed to handle the load.